# Do we know the history of Bas Lag

Tags: china-mieville, bas-lag

I have just finished reading China Miéville's Bas-Lag sequence of novels and am wondering if there are any short stories or interviews with the author where he states definitively what the history of Bas-Lag is? Is it for example an alternate earth? A a colony world after some catastrophic event? This later is likely and even discussed to an extent in the second Bas-Lag novel The Scar, with reference to the Ghosthead Empire, but even the characters themselves seem unsure of the history of their world and come to no definitive conclusions. To sum up is there a short story or stories, or even an interview with the author where he either makes the history of Bas-Lag explicit or expands upon what appears in the three Bas-Lag novels?

Comment: Not much is known about the history. It's just a fantasy world - some urban fantasy mixed up. While some bit like year may muddle it up, but it's just that.

Answer (score 1):

[Dragon Magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_(magazine)) did a couple of Bas-Lag focus articles in 2007, in issue 352 to be exact, which included an interview with China. In that article there is a timeline that includes dates for things like the Ghosthead Empire, the Malarial Queendom, The Pirate Wars and the Ravening that destroyed the Khepri civilisation. You can now also find those same dates in [this Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bas-Lag). In terms of the origin of the world it is an original creation and we don't know where it came from as a whole. The history related by Uther Doul in *The Scar* suggests that the human and other populations (like the Anophelii, Khepri, Cactacae, Hotchi, etc...) already existed when the beings known as the Ghosthead crash landed and consequently took over large parts of the world using Probability technology.